# How can I format this gatsby-config.js file in order to create a dummy node for a canvas module?

Tags: reactjs, config, gatsby

Currently I am having trouble having gatsby build my HTML renderer due to my poor config knowledge. I tried finding examples online of configs and read the documentation but can't seem to get the order right here.

```js
module.exports = {

  exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
    if (stage === "build-html" || stage === "develop-html") {
      actions.setWebpackConfig({
        module: {
          rules: [
            {
              test: /canvas/,
              use: loaders.null(),
            },
          ],
        },
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: "gatsby-theme-portfolio-minimal",
            options: {
              siteUrl: "https://gatsby-starter-portfolio-minimal-theme.netlify.app/", // Used for sitemap generation
              manifestSettings: {
                favicon: "./content/images/favicon.png", // Path is relative to the root
                siteName: "My Minimal Portfolio", // Used in manifest.json
                shortName: "Portfolio", // Used in manifest.json
                startUrl: "/", // Used in manifest.json
                backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF", // Used in manifest.json
                themeColor: "#000000", // Used in manifest.json
                display: "minimal-ui", // Used in manifest.json
              },
              contentDirectory: "./content",
              blogSettings: {
                path: "/blog", // Defines the slug for the blog listing page
                usePathPrefixForArticles: false, // Default true (i.e. path will be /blog/first-article)
              },
              // googleAnalytics: {
              //     trackingId: "UA-XXXXXX-X",
              //     anonymize: true, // Default true
              //     environments: ["production", "development"] // Default ["production"]
              // }
            },
          },
        ]
      })
    }
  }



};
```

Am I missing a comma somewhere or something? I keep getting this error.

```
Error: C:\Users\jakub\Sites\portfolio-minimal\gatsby-config.js:5
    exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
           ^
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

The error above is from an attempt to fix this error.

```
 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating SSR bundle failed

Unexpected character '�' (1:2)

File: node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node:1:2

not finished Building HTML renderer - 8.688s
```

And the exports.onCreateWebpackConfig came from [this post](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/17661#issuecomment-532424504)

When defined outside module.exports, it refers me to my first error #98123 as so.

```js
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html" || stage === "develop-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /canvas/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}

module.exports = {

  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-theme-portfolio-minimal",
      options: {
        siteUrl: "https://gatsby-starter-portfolio-minimal-theme.netlify.app/", // Used for sitemap generation
        manifestSettings: {
          favicon: "./content/images/favicon.png", // Path is relative to the root
          siteName: "My Minimal Portfolio", // Used in manifest.json
          shortName: "Portfolio", // Used in manifest.json
          startUrl: "/", // Used in manifest.json
          backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF", // Used in manifest.json
          themeColor: "#000000", // Used in manifest.json
          display: "minimal-ui", // Used in manifest.json
        },
        contentDirectory: "./content",
        blogSettings: {
          path: "/blog", // Defines the slug for the blog listing page
          usePathPrefixForArticles: false, // Default true (i.e. path will be /blog/first-article)
        },
        // googleAnalytics: {
        //     trackingId: "UA-XXXXXX-X",
        //     anonymize: true, // Default true
        //     environments: ["production", "development"] // Default ["production"]
        // }
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing configurations between `gatsby-node.js` and `gatsby-config.js`. webpack-related configuration must be placed in `gatsby-node.js` while all plugin-related stuff must be placed in `gatsby-config.js`. Your final configuration should look like this:

In your `gatsby-node.js`:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html" || stage === "develop-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /canvas/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

In your `gatsby-config.js`:

```
module.exports = {

  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-theme-portfolio-minimal",
      options: {
        siteUrl: "https://gatsby-starter-portfolio-minimal-theme.netlify.app/", // Used for sitemap generation
        manifestSettings: {
          favicon: "./content/images/favicon.png", // Path is relative to the root
          siteName: "My Minimal Portfolio", // Used in manifest.json
          shortName: "Portfolio", // Used in manifest.json
          startUrl: "/", // Used in manifest.json
          backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF", // Used in manifest.json
          themeColor: "#000000", // Used in manifest.json
          display: "minimal-ui", // Used in manifest.json
        },
        contentDirectory: "./content",
        blogSettings: {
          path: "/blog", // Defines the slug for the blog listing page
          usePathPrefixForArticles: false, // Default true (i.e. path will be /blog/first-article)
        },
        // googleAnalytics: {
        //     trackingId: "UA-XXXXXX-X",
        //     anonymize: true, // Default true
        //     environments: ["production", "development"] // Default ["production"]
        // }
      },
    },
  ],
};
```